# itextsharp pdf is created but not displaying in browser

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, itext

I am using ITextSharp to create a print friendly PDF which is currently not being displayed in the browser.

Generation of the PDF is handled via clicking on a print icon which trigger the jquery below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function printDiv() {
    $.post("@Url.Action("DownloadAdultReportPdf", "Monthly")",
    {
        RegionId: $("#RegionId").val(),
        DatCodeId: $("#DatCodeId").val(),
        AgencyId: $("#AgencyId").val(),
        ReportVersionId: $("#ReportVersionId").val()
    });
}
```

The print icon code looks like this:

```
<input class="print-icon tooltip" title="print this report" type="image" src="~/Content/images/printer-icon-23.png" onclick="printDiv()"/>
```

clicking on this icon goes to a FileResult in the MonthlyController called DownloadAdultReportPdf the code for this is shown below:

```
public FileResult DownloadAdultReportPdf(AdultViewModel model)
    {
        MemoryStream workStream = new MemoryStream();
        DateTime dTime = DateTime.Now;
        string strPDFFileName = string.Format("SamplePdf" + dTime.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + "-" + ".pdf");
        Document doc = new Document();
        doc.NewPage();
        Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
        paragraph.Add("Hello World!");
        doc.SetMargins(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f);

        string strAttachment = Server.MapPath("~/Downloads/" + strPDFFileName);

        PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, workStream).CloseStream = false;
        doc.Open();
        doc.Add(paragraph);
        doc.Close();

        byte[] byteInfo = workStream.ToArray();
        workStream.Write(byteInfo, 0, byteInfo.Length);
        workStream.Position = 0;

        return File(workStream, "application/pdf", strPDFFileName);
    }
```

How do I get the PDF to be displayed in the users browser?

Comment: browsers must have capability to ready pdf. and have u debug the code on `return File(workStream,....)` any error ??

Comment: the browser I am testing in is the latest version of Chrome, when I intellisense over the workStream variable I am getting ReadTimeout and WriteTimeout error  in both cases is shown as a System.InvalidOperationException

Comment: there is two issue first to craete pdf is not working and second with your jquery code page will not redirect to download/View the pdf because when your jquery `post` calls returns file there is no `success` function define to take care of response.

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues in your C# code:

```
Document doc = new Document();
doc.NewPage();
```

You use the `Document doc` without having associated a `PdfWriter` with it and opening it. In particular instructions which may change page content this way are likely to get lost. The missing steps eventually are executed here:

```
PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, workStream).CloseStream = false;
doc.Open();
doc.Add(paragraph);
doc.Close();

byte[] byteInfo = workStream.ToArray();
workStream.Write(byteInfo, 0, byteInfo.Length);
```

You here effectively get a copy of the finished PDF in `byteInfo` and *append it to the finishedPDF in `workStream`!* Thus, `workStream` now contains two identical copies of the PDF in sequence.

```
workStream.Position = 0;
return File(workStream, "application/pdf", strPDFFileName);
```

Thus, here you return a `MemoryStream` with two copies of finished PDF.

Fix these issues to have a valid PDF to display.

Further issues might exist in your JavaScript code.